# using template_directory in wordpress header sends user to the wrong domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm setting up a wordpress site and coding in the header.php file  of my directory. the code for the links on the navbar are as follows:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/page/">Page</a>
```

But when this is selected, instead of taking the user to the domain that i expect, which is www.mydomain.com/page (which has been the case every other time I have done this approach) it take the user to the following:

"www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/page"

This is really weird, and I have not experienced it before.

I am editing the code via FTP (FileZilla) and using a custom Wordpress theme I built myself. When I ran this on a localhost it worked fine, the issue didn't occur until I started running it on the server. I am doing this because my client is using DreamHost and they do not have a cPanel or File Editor for the plan we use.

Would anyone have any starting point as to why this is occurring? I will attempt to root out  more information and update this with more info as I find it.

Comment: What exactly you want to display? you have `store` as a page? or is it in theme file as `store.php`?

Comment: ah yes the store.php is just a page saying the store is coming soon. This could be any of the pages, I am going to edit the question now to just do a generic page

Comment: Oh! than why don't you create a custom page template for that and add new menu location for certain area and DONE! Ta-Da!

Comment: Yeah and that’s fine to do it like that just to get it done but at this time I’d like to figure out why it isn’t working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. I went off of Amila Priyankara's answer so I give them most of the credit here.

Instead of

`<?php site_url( '/store/', 'https' );?>`

Like they suggested, i used

`<?php echo get_site_url('www.mydomain.com', '/store/', 'https' );?>`

Thanks to the research at the link below. This is because we have to display the link using echo, and the `<?php get_template_directory(); ?>`was returning the full template directory, rather than just the site url.

I'm still not quite sure why this has never caused me problems before, but this is good to know that this is another way to solve it.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php site_url( '/store/', 'https' );?>
```

Try this one.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/

Comment: Thanks but it’s still doing it

Comment: how about this **<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>** Will this sort it out

Comment: See below, I did a spinoff of your initial answer, but it eventually fixed it, thanks for your help!